# MongoDB - Getting error while connect with local data base

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a User list when user submit their details. In `app.js` I have the function for that.

like this:

```
app.post('/addList', userList.submit);
```

I am calling my function which is nested in userList.submit:

```
var sendList = require('../model/model');

exports.list = function(req, res){
  res.send("respond with a resource this is from list file");
};

exports.addList = function(req, res, next){
    res.render('index', {title:'title from list.js'});
};

exports.submit = function(req,res,next){
    var name = req.body.name,
        dept = req.body.dept;

    sendList.create({
        name:name,
        dept:dept
    }, function(error){
        console.log('Erros is ', error);
        if (error) return next(error);
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

In the model folder, `model.js` has the function as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/user_list');

var schema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    dept:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

But I am getting error saying:

```
var schema = new Schema({
                 ^
ReferenceError: Schema is not defined
```

What is this mean? where I made the mistake? any one figure out and help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema is defined as a property of mongoose. It's not there in the global scope of nodejs.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    dept:String
});
```

Comment: But I have another application, which i am using to upload the files, it works fine.. how?

Comment: It's basic programming. When you say `new Schema`, you need to have a javascript function (in this case a constructor) named `Schema` defined somewhere. How can you call a function which is not defined?

Comment: In your other app, there must be a line like `var Schema = mongoose.Schema`

Comment: There is no line like so. I understand that, that's a photo upload form, which stores the photos in local folder. so it may not needed. Am I correct?

Comment: Yup. I assumed you are saving the photos in mongodb gridfs since your question was on mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Schema is part of an application or is a property of mongoose. It has nothing to do with db, it's only mapping db into js objects. 
 you have to change the code `: = new mogoose.schema ({` what ever you  want ..